# $j is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery event.

In HTML

```
<div class="opsContainer"></div>
```

I am adding this for jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In script I have this:

```
$j("div.opsContainer").css({width:"1057px",height:"696px",border:"1px solid #000",background:"white",margin: "0 auto","border-radius":"1px"});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2wq3zkz/)

It is not working if I have `$j`. If I replace `$j` with `$` it will work.

Can anyone help and explain why it is not working.

Comment: Why you expect `$j` to be defined?

Comment: $ is the alias for jQuery, what do you think $j is?

Comment: Today i got a sample code from my team they have added that.

Comment: It's a custom alias for jQuery which needs to be defined!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this code to make it working (JQUERY noConflict)

```
var $j = $.noConflict();
```

This will allow you to use $j instead of $.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$` , `jQuery` or `var $j = $.noConflict();` :

```js
$("div.opsContainer").css({width:"1057px",height:"696px",border:"1px solid #000",background:"white",margin: "0 auto","border-radius":"1px"});

//or

//jQuery("div.opsContainer").css({width:"1057px",height:"696px",border:"1px solid #000",background:"white",margin: "0 auto","border-radius":"1px"});
//or this
    //var $j = $.noConflict();
//$j("div.opsContainer").css({width:"1057px",height:"696px",border:"1px solid #000",background:"white",margin: "0 auto","border-radius":"1px"});
```

```html
    <div class="opsContainer"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need **j** after **$**
More exapmles with jQuery selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).